# Pandas Check if a Row Exists Anywhere in a Column and Return True or False

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to check is a row is present anywhere in another column and return True / False in a column called 'Check'.

Specifically I'm trying to lookup the values in a column called 'Keyword', and check if it exists anywhere in a column called description.

Each keyword to check is 2 words+ and I'm looking to find the word in the exact order.

```
Keyword        Description                Check
spam spam      spam spam foo bar          True
spam foo                                  True
spam bar                                  False
spam spam foo                             True
spam bar                                  False
```

**My code:**

```
df['Check'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Keyword'] in row['Description'], axis=1)
```

This checks if the keyword is in a matching row, but I need to check if it existing anywhere in the entire column instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) method against a `list` of values. So you need a proper `list` of `Description` column values:

```
In [915]: vals = [x.split() for x in df.Description.values][0]
In [917]: df['Check'] = df.Keyword.isin(vals)

In [918]: df
Out[918]: 
  Keyword        Description  Check
0    spam  eggs spam foo bar   True
1    eggs                      True
2   house                     False
3     foo                      True
4     bar                      True
5  turtle                     False
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have given a better example, but the keywords in the Keyword column are 2 words + in length. This solution breaks the Description values into single words which can't be matched.

Comment: Please edit your question to have proper sample data with expected output.

Comment: Edited as requested. Thanks again for any help.